# Ubuntu 18.10 apps not start

Tags: command-line, nautilus

I have a problem with my ubuntu 18.10, all "systems" apps like terminal, nautilus, cheese, ecc... not start, if I click on it, but if I open a terminal and launch it by command it starts.

Can you help me please??

This is my Linux:

Linux 4.18.0-12-generic #13-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 14 15:17:05 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this problem also. I had installed Chrome Remote Desktop in the past. Once I removed that (`sudo apt-get autoremove chrome-remote-desktop`) everything seems to work again, including terminal and nautilus.